# Установить Location у time.Time в nil; равенство time.Time

Tags: golang, часовые-пояса

В тестах использую `reflect.DeepEqual`, но он не работает,
когда время, полученное из `time.Now()` сравнивается со
временем, которое, например, декодировано из *JSON*:

```go
fmt.Println(timeFromNow == timeFromJSON)
// Output:
//   false
```

`time.In` паникует, если ему передать `nil`.  Как
удалить `Location` из времени, а также стереть показания
монотонных счётчиков, чтобы получить время, эквивалентное
декодированному из *JSON*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Стирание монотонных счётчиков производится через метод
`Truncate(0)`, а `nil` в поле `loc`
устанавливается, когда вы передаёте зону *UTC*:

```go
fmt.Println(timeFromNow.Truncate(0).UTC() == timeFromJSON)
// Output:
//   true
```

*Playground*:
https://play.golang.org/p/cHydrLE8b0j